# API shopify - change quantities of multiple products with a single API call

Tags: api, graphql, shopify

i have a problema with shopify's API.

i tried with GraphQL but i couldn't figure out how it works, and the queries keep returning errors. Can anyone explain to me how it works?

This operation its possibile with the simple shopify's API?

below one of the GraphQL queries used:
mutation{
inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation(
locationId: "gid://shopify/Location/{LOCATON_ID}",
inventoryItemAdjustments:[
{variantId: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/{VARIANT_ID}", availableDelta: 10},
{variantId: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/{VARIANT_ID}", availableDelta: 5}
]
){
inventoryLevels{
id
available
}
userErrors{
field
message
}
}
}